# How can I make Cocoapods.org discover that my pod has Tests?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, cocoapods, podspec

I've got a pod on Cocoapods with tests, but cocoapods.org is saying the pod has no tests. How can I do it? What I'm doing wrong?

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SearchEmojiOnString
https://github.com/GabrielMassana/SearchEmojiOnString-iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code isn't too complex:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoadocs.org/blob/master/classes/testing_idealist.rb

Roughly:

- Get all projects in the root dir
- Get all test targets in those projects
- Loop through all associated files, looking for common test patterns
- look for common expectations via regexes e.g.

  `regexes = [/XCTAssert|XCTFail/,                 # XCTest
             /expect\(/,                          # Expecta, Nimble
             /should\]|shouldNot\]/,              # Kiwi
             /assertThat/,                        # OCHamcrest
             / should .*;| should_not |expect\(/, # Cedar
             /FBSnapshotVerify/                   # FBSnapshotTestCase
           ]`
- Count all of those matches, and put that number [into the DB](http://metrics.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/Gloss) as `total_test_expectations`.

Judging on my comments inline, we've had problems before with Unicode in the Xcode project. Perhaps that's your problem, would appreciate a PR if you can figure it out.

Comment: I solved the problem thx to your answer. I was using `NSAssert` instead of `XCTAssert`. I updated it, and now Cocoapods is detecting my tests.